# while loop with time.sleep() causes "double free or corruption"

Tags: python, while-loop, cython, sleep

I am a writing a wrapper for a C-API with Cython. The goal is to build a `client` which connects to a `mediator` server using the API. The client process a audio file, splits it into packages and sends them to the mediator. Short before sending the audio packets he starts an additional thread for receiving incoming packets from the mediator. The API method for receiving packets from the mediator is called with released gil `no gil`. Nevertheless, after finishing to send all the outgoing packets the client has to wait. He is still receiving packets from the mediator and has to wait for a `done` message on mediators part. Only then he is allowed to disconnect from the mediator.

```
DO STUFF
...
t = threading.Thread(target=_recv_thread, args=(user_data,))
t.start()
...
send_audio_packets()
while True:
    if user_data.proceed is 1:
        print("Still waiting")
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        disconnect()
```

To disconnect the user_data.proceed value has to be set to 0 after receiving the last packet.
The problem I am now encountering is that the `time.sleep()` causes a `double free or corruption (fasttop) Aborted`. Is it possible that this error has to do something with the other "thread"?

Comment: I don't think the `sleep()` call is _causing_ the double free – it's probably uncovering it due to a timing/race issue. Have you attempted to debug using `gdb` or such? What is the API you're wrapping?

Comment: Yes: `time.sleep` is *very* unlikely to cause a double free. If this happens all the time, you can easily remove (or not start) the other thread, and find out.

Comment: Hey, if I comment out sleep() it works, but I don't understand why.. I didn't debugged it yet. The API is https://github.com/ELITR/pv-platform-sample-connector

Comment: Are you sure the API you're wrapping is thread-safe at all?

Comment: They are describing a implementation of example client in C in their documentation which also uses two threads. Whilst I shut of the start of the receiving and still the getting the abortion error. You're right the error is not caused by time.sleep(). The generated c file of the cython compiler throws an error. I have to get the debugger running. Thanks for your help